# Being notified when some YouTube video in some post becomes unavailable

Tags: plugins, youtube

Is there a plugin or some PHP code that notifies you whenever a YouTube videos becomes unavailable in some post of a WordPress website ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://ifttt.com to set up a YouTube channel notification.

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't any ifttt triggers for when a YouTube video becomes unavailable.

Comment: Well, I am sure that can be arranged and/or built in. They are only in beta right now.