# How to be notified when a YT video becomes unavailable on my website?

Tags: youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Being notified when some YouTube video in some post becomes unavailable](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37772/being-notified-when-some-youtube-video-in-some-post-becomes-unavailable)

I asked this question almost one year ago. Perhaps now somebody has developed some plugin to do that : receiving a notification when a YT video embedded in some page of my website becomes unavailable.

I have many YT videos on my site, and I want to know very quickly if one of them was deleted by YT, so that I can fix the problem right away. This is a very common problem for which I suspect a lot of people would like a solution.

Comment: Does YouTube provide such information in any form? Please add any research you have already performed. Also please elaborate how are you adding videos since different methods are used (pasting embed code in source, oEmbed, plugins, etc).

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42456/how-to-make-simply-report-button-on-posts for a plugin. It hassome quirks and needs more work though.

Comment: ↑ This is your old question. Edit it and it gets back on the front page. opening a new one is no option.